# Selenium-Maximo "cant invoke public java.lang.object[][] framework.AutomationBaseTest.getBrowsers()"

Tags: eclipse, selenium, jenkins, testng, maximo

Trying to run selenium that are specifically packaged by IBM for maximo. When I run the scripts throught Eclipse IDE, they work fine. However, I am trying to run the TestNG scripts through Jenkins, therefore I need to be able to run them in the command line. I used this command:

```
java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -ea -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -classpath C:\commandLine\testng.jar;C:\Users\zunigmx\Documents\workspace4\Automation\classes;C:\Users\zunigmx\Documents\workspace4\Automation\lib\* org.testng.TestNG C:\commandLine\testng-customsuite.xml
```

And got this error:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post the full stack trace as text instead of an image. That image will no longer be available at some point and the question will be less useful.

Answer (score 1):

This typically happens when you have a class which satisfies the following traits :

- Your class has a parameterized constructor which is annotated using the annotation `@Factory`
- Your constructor which is marked as a factory method is combined with a data provider which also resides in the same class.

Now when TestNG encounters that the constructor of your class is marked with the annotation `@Factory` and is coupled with a data provider it will try to look for a method which is annotated using the `@DataProvider` annotation and whose name matches with the data provider name. Once it finds this method (in your case that method is `getBrowsers()` TestNG tries using reflection to instantiate your class and then invoke this data provider method. But here, TestNG cannot instantiate your class because your class as a parameterized constructor and so TestNG doesn't know what to pass to the constructor so that your class can be instantiated. Since your data provider method is also an instance method, TestNG is stuck.

To fix this problem you would need to make your `getBrowsers()` method a static method and try again.

This behavior is the same irrespective of how the test is executed (either via Jenkins or via eclipse IDE)